# A Function that creates a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not sure whether this is possible.  I know it sounds like something a virus would try to do.

I have over 400 Spreadsheets that were created from a template.
I have been asked if it is possible for headings to be frozen on certain sheets.
While I know this is possible, the headings are actually on the third table on the Sheet.  As data still needs to be added to the first 2 tables and the 3rd start at row 19, it is not a solution to freeze the top 19 and hide the top 18 rows.  Freezing the top 19 will freeze most of the screen.

I was thinking that if the active row was >= 30 then it could automate the hiding of the top 18 rows.  Is there a way to automate inserting or exporting code into each spreadsheet, or some other feature I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you didn't provide any examples nor code samples,
I understand you want to use 1 script over 400 spreadsheets.

**Workaround:**

1. Use [Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) / [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to list and filter all your spreadsheets.
2. Apply [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) for each of your spreadsheets.

**Reference:**

- [Drive API > Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [setFrozenRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setfrozenrowsrows)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I had been wondering if it was actually possible for 1 script to insert code into 400 Spreadsheets as a new script file.

Comment: @GlibGibon you can manage your spreadsheets with just 1 script.